# DocumentDB Never Creates Document

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm trying to insert a document into `my-documents` in the storage database `my-db` but this isn't happening.

I create a document client like this-

```
  _endpointUri = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.DocumentDBEndpoint);
  _privateKey = Properties.Settings.Default.DocumentDBKey;
  _databaseName = Properties.Settings.Default.DocumentDBDatabase;
  _collectionName = collectionName;
  _collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName);

  _documentClient = new DocumentClient(_endpointUri, _privateKey);
```

I then try to insert a document into the collection.

```
public async Task Set(T document)
{
  await _documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(_collectionUri.ToString(), document);
}
```

I tried passing the `_collectionUri` as well as the `toString` and they both do the same thing. If I step through the debugger the `toString` of that collection uri looks like-

**dbs/my-db/colls/my-documents**

I've tried set `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on the call, as well as not awaiting it at all. Of course when it's not awaited it steps over the line fine, but no document ever gets added to the `my-documents` collection.

I'm not sure if i'm using CreateDocumentAsync (also tried `UpsertDocumentAsync`) because not errors are thrown.

Can anyone see from the information given what mistake I'm making?

**Edit** In my testing with Azure I did opt to use DocumentDB with MongoDB Api. That may be related. Since I can easily blow it all away I will recreate it using the DocumentDB Api and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Creating a database with MongoDB compatibility shouldn't affect your ability to make native calls via DocumentDB protocol + related SDK's.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be two different problems I assumed were the same.

**Document Not Creating-**

So I set this up originally to use the MongoDB driver which dumped my databases/collections in Azure Storage. The issue of the documents never getting created was because DocumentDB doesn't store itself in the Azure Storage resource. When you create a new DocumentDB look under Settings > Collections > Browse to see that no databases exist. Unfortunately it doesn't appear DocumentDB has a desktop db management application and this needs to be done on the azure portal.

So the issue was, plainly, that the database/collection I was pointing to didn't exist for the above reason.

**Await Never Returning-**

Apparently if you're going to await something you need to await all the way through the call stack.

`(async) POST:Api (awaits)` -> `(async) Service:CreateDocument` -> `(async) Repository:Set (awaits)` -> `(async) DocumentClient:CreateDocumentAsync`

The problem was that even though my service was async, it was not *awaiting* the call to `Repository:Set`. Awaiting everything up the chain allowed me to step-through and receive a response from the server.